# Starting over with Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I decided to learn how to use Version Control over Christmas break, so I downloaded Git, opened a GitHub account and started reading the online tutorial linked to from the GitHub website.  When I got to this part http://progit.org/book/ch2-2.html I got stuck because I wasn't sure how to add files.  For instance, I tried

```
git add C:/Finish.txt
```

And it said

```
Fatal:  'C:/Finish.txt' is outside repository
```

I was confused until I remember that a long time ago I had tried teaching myself Ruby on Rails and played around with Git back then.  It never really went anywhere, but there's all this residual stuff floating around my system and I don't know how to change it.  For instance, my Untracked files (which should be empty) are rails_projects/ and sample/.

How can I just erase all the old stuff and start over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make a folder for your repository, move Finish.txt to that repository, then do git add.

For example:

```
# here you create C:\myrepo
cd C:\myrepo
git init .
# here you edit C:\myrepo\Finish.txt
git add Finish.txt
git commit -m "Added Finish.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Start a new repository, e.g.

```
 c:
 md c:\newrepo
 cd c:\newrepo
 git init .
 copy \Finish.txt .
 git add Finish.txt
 git commit -m "started over"
```

I strongly recommend *against* adding anything to C:\, let alone putting a git repo *there*. Unless of course you want to accidentally add all of your system disk to git :)

I can also heartily recommend using TortoiseGit which has some excellent explorer integration.

Comment: true enough. habit of mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete any `.git` folder that you find in your drive.

To create a repo go to a folder that you want the repo in ( and not just randomly), do:

```
git init
```

Then proceed... Add only files that you put within this repo and not randomly from some location.

Comment: Delete _any_ .git folder in your drive? Woah, risky advice. Allthough I agree, I don't expect the guy/girl has git repositories all over the place yet :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be very unusual to have the root directory of your hard drive be a git repository.  That's probably why it's giving you the error.

git repositories are typically in a subdirectory and that subdirectory is typically a project.

To initialize a subdirectory as a git repository, you'd do:

```
git init (directory)
```

Then you'd add your files and commit.

Comment: @Andrew Latham - if you have a .git in your root, I agree that's a bad thing. I would delete that unless you have something important in there.

Comment: Gotcha, I think I understand better now what exactly Git does.

Comment: @EbenGeer - disagree.  It's not a bad thing at all to have git in your root and could be perfectly valid.  However, it would be quite unusual, the way most people use git.

Comment: @wadesworld He's just learning Git and version control in general.